# Setting cell subtitle in search table view

Tags: iphone, loops, uitableview

I am looping through data, but in this data it has two names which are exactly the same but both have a different sub topic (which is suppose to be the subtitle). So the search results show both the names with the same subtitle when they should both have different subtitles as they have different subtopics.

I thought the following code would work but it doesn't and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *kCellID = @"cellID";
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCellIdentifier";

// if search is active display cell with subtitles otherwise display default
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchFilteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for(id obj in data){
        if ([[obj valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:[self.searchFilteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"subTopic"]);
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [obj valueForKey:@"subTopic"];
        }
    }

    return cell;

}else{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

}

The `NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"subTopic"])` shows the correct sub topics but it doesn't display those results in the subtitles on the search table view.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using an appropriate `UITableViewCellStyle` with this (anything but `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` should thus work). The cell's style is specified when you initialize it.

```
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Comment: I think I've done that for my code for the first branch of 'if statements' where subtitles are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You use the same cell Identifier for 2 different kinds of cell, which may cause some issues when dequeueing them, you should use 2 different cell identifiers.

Also, you should break out of your loop:

```
    for(id obj in data){
    if ([[obj valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:[self.searchFilteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"subTopic"]);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [obj valueForKey:@"subTopic"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried the changes you suggested but I still seem to have the same problem, except the two names have the same subtitle of the first name. Before they had the same subtitle of the second name.